# How to get / store return value from stored procedure call in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spIn  
    (@value1 varchar(100),
     @value2 varchar(100),)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.In(value1, value2,)
    VALUES (@value1, @value2,)
END
RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY()
GO
```

In code it is like

```
using (DBEntities dataContext = new DBEntities())
{
    dataContext.spIn(value1,value2);
}
```

How to store the identity value??

FYI while function import I have given as Scalars of type `Int32`, if I check the column information no column is there.

Comment: whats the return value of `dataContext.spIn(value1,value2);` ???

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but at minimum use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead of `@@IDENTITY`

Comment: The return type of `dataContext.spIn` should be the identity, thought it will likely be `IEnumerable<int>` and not `int` and it should have just one value.

Comment: it should return identity value which is int, if i am trying to store the same as int32 id_Value = Convert.ToInt32 (dataContext.spIn(value1,value2)); 
i am getting conversion value, i tried 
var id_Value = Convert.ToInt32 (dataContext.spIn(value1,value2)); too , but that var is not having the identity value at all   @nozzleman

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion , But in this case i cant change it @Crowcoder

Comment: so am i need to use it like  IEnumerable<int> id_value =dataContext.spIn(value1,value2)   @juharr

Comment: Try `int id_Value = dataContext.spIn(value1,value2).First();`.  If that doesn't work hover over `spIn` and tell us what the return type is for that method.

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult<int?>' to 'int' got this error on compilation @juharr

Comment: Now i added the same data type i.e. System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult<int?> id_value =dataContext.spIn(value1,value2) , its returning a object of lots of data/info , where can i find the identity value in that

Comment: OK since it's a nullable `int` you'll need to get the `Value` like this `int id_Value = dataContext.spIn(value1,value2).First().Value;`

Comment: The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Decimal' type to a nullable 'System.Int32' type is not valid. got this exception

Comment: Now after changing SP i am getting "The data reader returned by the store data provider does not have enough columns for the query requested."  but there it is auto generated one at abcd.designer.cs file is

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spIn  
    (@value1 varchar(100),
     @value2 varchar(100),)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.In(value1, value2,)
    VALUES (@value1, @value2,)
END
SELECT @@IDENTITY AS id
GO
```

and the code change is as below

```
using (DBEntities dataContext = new DBEntities())
{
   int  = ID Convert.ToInt32(dataContext.spIn(value1,value2).FirstOrDefault().id); 
}
```